# full column rank of observability matrix if $C \succ 0$

Tags: matrices, control-theory

Suppose I know that $C\succ 0$, and that $A$ is asymptotically stable.

Can I say the observability matrix $\mathcal{O}$ is full column rank?

where $\mathcal{O} = \begin{bmatrix} C \\ CA \\ \vdots \\ CA^{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$

---

$A$ is asymptotically stable implies all eigenvalues of $A$ are of negative real part.

Comment: Does $C\succ0$ mean that $C$ is a positive definite matrix, so square, symmetric and all eigenvalues positive real?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $C\succ0$ implies that $C$ is already full rank, then the observability matrix $\mathcal{O}$ is also always full rank, independently of $A$. Because the rank of $\mathcal{O}$ should at least be equal to that of $C$.